# React Native: FlatList Header with size defined by text height sometimes won't display fully

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist with a header defined in the *renderHeader* function here, and it exhibits strange jumpy behaviour or will not display at all which can be fixed by reloading the flatlist again. The issue only appears when I do not give the header an explicit height and instead use the text size + padding to be the height (as the code snippet shows). Setting the flex value to 1 on the *ListHeaderComponentStyle* prop will fix the jumpiness/text not showing but causes more problems while loading. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Code for reference:

```
  <FlatList
    ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
    data={retrieveItems()}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
    contentContainerStyle={{flexgrow: 1}}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    scrollEventThrottle={55}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => renderItems(item, index)}
    keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
    ListEmptyComponent={renderNoItems}
  />
```

```
const renderHeader = () => (
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "stretch",
                margin: 0 -20}}>
     <View style={{flex: 1,
                   flexDirection: "row",
                   alignItems: "center",
                   margin 0 20}}>
      <View style={{padding: 10 50, alignSelf: "center"}}>
        <Text>sample text</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
///<View/ > another unrelated view in header
</View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem was the flex: 1 styling on the views needed to be removed. After doing that it works fine.